# Check if an user and password match in arrays

Tags: php

I made a form to get an user and password and then I need to compare the user with an array where is the users and compare the password with another array where is the passwords, I guess that the first position of the users array is matched with the first position of the passwords array, so for example if i get the third user and the third password i say that is correct and if is not correct i say is wrong.

I tried the following code with php but not works and Im stuck here.

```
<?php
$user=$_GET['user'];
$password=$_GET['password'];

$users=array('Antonio', ' Juan', 'Sonia', 'Manuel', 'Lourdes', 'Fernando');
$passwords=array('adr3','dfe4','dde3','dfd4','yhf7','eer8');
$numofusers=count($users);

for($i=0; $i<=$numofusers; $i++){
    if(($user == users[$i]) && ($password == $passwords[$i])){
        echo "The user and password match";
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "The user and password dont match";
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

With the actual code says always that dont match.

Comment: There's a typo on line 10, missing a dollar on `$users` variable.

Comment: You could restructure your user and password array to combine them - something like `$users=array('Antonio' => 'adr3',...`, you could then check `$users[$user] == $password`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you **`exit`** your script after **first** check whether it's correct or not. Do something like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<=$numofusers; $i++){
    // also fix `users` with `$users`
    if(($user == $users[$i]) && ($password == $passwords[$i])){
        echo "The user and password match";
        exit;
    }
}

echo "The user and password dont match";
exit;
```